# Extract a table from website and save it as csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv, data-analysis

I want to extract the table with div element as `ind-mp_info` to a csv file. You can find it when you expand the `COVID-19 Statewise Status` tab.
The website link is- https://www.mygov.in/covid-19/

The code-

```
    # importing the libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import csv
import pandas as pd

html = urlopen("https://www.mygov.in/covid-19/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"ind-mp_info"})
rows = table.findAll("tr")

with open("editors.csv", "wt+", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        csv_row = []
        for cell in row.findAll(["td", "th"]):
            csv_row.append(cell.get_text())
        writer.writerow(csv_row)
```

Comment: ...and where do I find your code?

Comment: Please check now

Comment: the soup is good? is the scraping part ok? where is the problem?

Comment: Actually the `table` doesn't get any data. It throws as `NoneType`.

Comment: Your problem is that the table on the website is added using javascript and beautifulsoup is not executing javascript. You could use selenium which uses python to control a web browser but the answer by @chitown88 is a much better way.

Comment: {"class":"ind-mp_info"} should be ```{"class_":"ind-mp_info"}```

Answer (score 1):

You can get that json directly and convert to dataframe.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

url = 'https://www.mygov.in/sites/default/files/covid/vaccine/vaccine_counts_today.json'
payload = {
    'timestamp':int(time.time())}

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['vacc_st_data'])
df.to_csv('editors.csv',index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
                                     st_name state_id                          covid_state_name covid_state_id     dose1     dose2 total_doses last_dose1 last_dose2 last_total_doses
0                        Andaman and Nicobar        1                       Andaman and Nicobar             35    216987     95049      312036     216053      94601           310654
1                             Andhra Pradesh        2                            Andhra Pradesh             28  17826178   6298023    24124201   17633289    6216600         23849889
2                          Arunachal Pradesh        3                         Arunachal Pradesh             12    694525    189292      883817     692532     186724           879256
3                                      Assam        4                                     Assam             18  10706685   2259908    12966593   10510804    2209605         12720409
4                                      Bihar        5                                     Bihar             10  23504063   4521066    28025129   23366654    4488385         27855039
5                                 Chandigarh        6                                Chandigarh              4    706582    226814      933396     700329     223569           923898
6                               Chhattisgarh        7                              Chhattisgarh             22  10000779   2632861    12633640    9979765    2611797         12591562
7   Dadra and Nagar Haveli and Daman and Diu        8  Dadra and Nagar Haveli and Daman and Diu             26    587610     81895      669505     584400      80828           665228
8                                      Delhi        9                                     Delhi              7   7930829   3057218    10988047    7835664    3000596         10836260
9                                        Goa       10                                       Goa             30   1098302    307364     1405666    1094394     302521          1396915
10                                   Gujarat       11                                   Gujarat             24  28535938   9139961    37675899   28113725    9054592         37168317
11                                   Haryana       12                                   Haryana              6  10152822   2974775    13127597   10090001    2924714         13014715
12                          Himachal Pradesh       13                          Himachal Pradesh              2   4335980   1406772     5742752    4249932    1382642          5632574
13                         Jammu and Kashmir       14                         Jammu and Kashmir              1   5376054   1508641     6884695    5325806    1491262          6817068
14                                 Jharkhand       15                                 Jharkhand             20   8450135   2018319    10468454    8388534    1997186         10385720
15                                 Karnataka       16                                 Karnataka             29  26000864   7509346    33510210   25860894    7437119         33298013
16                                    Kerala       17                                    Kerala             32  15759471   6442507    22201978   15672348    6427551         22099899
17                                    Ladakh       18                                    Ladakh             37    188876     70779      259655     188699      70337           259036
18                               Lakshadweep       19                               Lakshadweep             31     51371     17296       68667      51165      17170            68335
19                            Madhya Pradesh       20                            Madhya Pradesh             23  29817764   5750317    35568081   29752302    5736096         35488398
20                               Maharashtra       21                               Maharashtra             27  35261712  12239857    47501569   35044144   12114068         47158212
21                                   Manipur       22                                   Manipur             14   1163534    251078     1414612    1159499     246753          1406252
22                                 Meghalaya       23                                 Meghalaya             17    946600    238582     1185182     938984     232152          1171136
23                                   Mizoram       24                                   Mizoram             15    656018    209089      865107     654946     206780           861726
24                                  Nagaland       25                                  Nagaland             13    634479    162621      797100     632129     159436           791565
25                                    Odisha       26                                    Odisha             21  14222570   4264500    18487070   13971009    4202596         18173605
26                                Puducherry       27                                Puducherry             34    604872    152636      757508     601608     151744           753352
27                                    Punjab       28                                    Punjab              3   8222725   2303559    10526284    8202118    2287403         10489521
28                                 Rajasthan       29                                 Rajasthan              8  27226185   8464839    35691024   27017475    8377435         35394910
29                                    Sikkim       30                                    Sikkim             11    498609    152574      651183     497851     151538           649389
30                                Tamil Nadu       31                                Tamil Nadu             33  21024528   4734496    25759024   20857302    4689811         25547113
31                                 Telangana       32                                 Telengana             36  11714148   4019069    15733217   11649833    3966309         15616142
32                                   Tripura       33                                   Tripura             16   2417276    808369     3225645    2411801     804137          3215938
33                             Uttar Pradesh       34                             Uttar Pradesh              9  46430534   8618231    55048765   45976210    8518342         54494552
34                               Uttarakhand       35                               Uttarakhand              5   5171059   1622492     6793551    5071246    1596762          6668008
35                               West Bengal       36                               West Bengal             19  23559058   9184539    32743597   23264439    9134008         32398447
36                             Miscellaneous       37                             Miscellaneous             38   1900366   1549702     3450068    1900173    1549042          3449215
```

Comment: Where did you find the jason file?

Comment: Look in dev tools and you can see that request being made.

Comment: Can you please do it same for `state wise data` since I needed that. The link is - https://www.mygov.in/sites/default/files/covid/covid_state_counts_ver1.json
There some special characters in json response which I am unable to handle.